# Center flex list item on screen resize

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a list which has `six li elements`. These by default all appear on one row.

On screen resize `540px`, I want the last li item (`item 6`) to go onto another row, but be center aligned (so below `item 3`).

Unsure what I'm doing wrong here:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul li {
  margin-right: .5em;
  border: 1px solid #a2a4a5;
  padding: 15px;
}

@media (max-width: 540px) {
  ul li {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Text 1</li>
    <li>Text 2</li>
    <li>Text 3</li>
    <li>Text 4</li>
    <li>Text 5</li>
    <li>Text 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add

```
justify-content: center
```

Or

```
 justify-content: space-between //This will look close to what you actually have in responsive mode
```

to your `ul`

There is no way to achieve it without touching to all the other flex items

Comment: Could've sworn I tried this before and it didn't work! But it works now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need the container to have a height of 100%, I used 100vh here for simplicity.

Your flex element also need to have a height of 100%, and because the flex-direction is row, you should use `align-items: center` to vertically center the content

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1em;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul li {
  margin-right: .5em;
  border: 1px solid #a2a4a5;
  padding: 15px;
}

@media (max-width: 540px) {
  ul li {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Text 1</li>
    <li>Text 2</li>
    <li>Text 3</li>
    <li>Text 4</li>
    <li>Text 5</li>
    <li>Text 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```